# Querying the current time of a city from terminal

Tags: command-line, time, timezone

I have friends all over the globe and before calling them I need to know their current time. Is there an application in Linux where one can query a city (if exists) in terminal (something like this): `time miami`

P.S: Yes I know that I can query it from Google but I prefer using the terminal

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `date` command will give you the current date/time based on your locale.
You can change that, one time only, by prefixing the command with a different timezone

```
TZ=CST6CDT date # Will print the current time in the USA Central time
TZ=Chicago date # will do the same, iff Chicago is listed by name in the /usr/share/zoneinfo/ dir hierarchy
```

Then to simplify ease of access, just create aliases in you .bashrc file, eg.

```
alias dad='TZ=Paris date'
alias fred='TZ=Amsterdam date'
```

etc.

Comment: very nice answer, thanks. let's say i want miami (not listed under /usr/share/zoneinfo/) and how do i find out its zone code (CST6...)?

Comment: You could use google maps or earth, but in this case I'll just tell you. Miami is in the Eastern Time zone, EST5EDT, same as New_York (Miami's just a little further south).
Quick G search, found and like [this](http://www.timeanddate.com/), gives TZ

Comment: “in the `/usr/share/zoneinfo` hierarchy”? I've never seen that. AFAIK you need the full path from the `zoneinfo` directory, e.g. `TZ=America/Chicago` or `TZ=Europe/Paris` or `TZ=Hongkong`.

Comment: Nope, just the City is enough, again I speak empirically. 
I tried it, and it works. I'm in America but the TZ=Paris worked fine. If I were going to rely on this, personally I'd stick with the EST5DST form.

Comment: Seems Gilles is right. It works for me only with full path.

Comment: Guess that is either version or distro specific. If you need to use this, as I stated I would recommend EST5DST form or Continent/City. Obviously, one should test before creating aliases. FWIW: I'm on an up to date Arch, with coreutils 8.15